# Condicional ciclo ng-if usando http service en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-directivas

Tengo un servicio http y con el código que tengo recibo 5 ids. Me gustaría llamarlos mediante un scope usando un ciclo `if`, el formato json tiene como propiedad `isFile` que si es falso es una carpeta y si es verdadero es un archivo. Mi idea es hacer un `if` que si es falso haga un ciclo que se repita que llame cada id de manera automatizada.

Una carpeta puede tener carpetas y archivos adentro.

Sin mas que decir aqui esta mi código.

*Controller*

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.accessfolders = [];
    $scope.files = [];
    var promise = $http.get("(Primer-Link)primera-llamada-obtuve-un-id")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return $http.get('(Segundo-Link)Use-el-id-de-la-primera-llamada-para-acceder-a-este-link', {
                params: {                          
                    id: response.data[0].Id //Obtuve el id de la primera llamada, Y llame a 3 carpetas y 2 archivos (quiero acceder a esas 3 carpetas usando un if)//
                }
            })
        })
    .then(function (response2) {
        console.log(response2);
        $scope.accessfolders = function () {
            if (response2.data.IsFile = false) //Tengo una propiedad llamada  IsFile, si IsFile = falso, el objecto es una carpeta//
                return $http.get('(Segundo-Link)Quiero-llamar-solo-las-carpetas-dentro-de-response2.data', { //fijaros que el primer link es para llamar el id de la carpeta principal y el segundo link para llamar a la carpeta que quiera usando su id//
                    params: {
                        id: response2.data[0].Id //No quiero usar [0] o [1], solo quisiera llamar cada que id obtuve con mi response2 de manera automatizada con un ciclo.//
                    }
                })
        }

        $scope.files = response2.data;
        return response2.data;
    })
})
```

*HTML*

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table class="table">
 <tr ng-repeat="file in files" ng-if="file.isFile == accessfolders">
  <td>{{file.Name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu quieres hacer llamadas ajax dependiendo de cuantos elementos sean carpetas en esa lista? El id inicial tiene algún binding y se puede cambiar?

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que quiero hacer, cada carpeta tiene su propio id para acceder a la carpeta que quiera.

Comment: En la segunda llamada a ajax `response2.data` lo que tiene es un arreglo con las carpetas y ficheros?

Comment: Si Exactamente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ejecutar código usando [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) y [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) con un [filtro](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) para filtrar los objetos que no quieres procesar.

Esto es posible ya que `ng-init` y `ng-repeat` se ejecutan con una prioridad de 450 y 1000 respectivamente. Siempre las directivas con mayor prioridad se ejecutan primero por lo que se garantiza que `ng-repeat` se procesará primero.

Te dejo un demo de como sería

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.files = [];

  // Esta función se ejecutará por cada elemento filtrado de la lista
  $scope.callFile = function(file) {
    $http.get('(Segundo-Link)', {
      params: {
        id: file.Id
      }
    })
  };

  // Haces la primer llamada
  $http.get("(Primer-Link)").then(function(response) {
    // Haces la segunda llamada partiendo de los resultados de la segunda
    return $http.get('(Segundo-Link)', {
      params: {
        id: response.data[0].Id
      }
    })
  }).then(function(response) {
    // Pones todos los resultados en una variable del scope
    $scope.files = response.data
  }).catch(function() {
    // Manejo de errores
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="file in files | filter : {IsFile: true}" ng-init="callFile(file)">
      <td>{{file.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```